# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actions_with_auth_user_as_actor'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to configure django-activity-stream for my project using the guidelines here [django-activity-stream](http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

I have models `User`(django-contrib-auth), `Article`

As mentioned in the docs, I register the models for the activity using the statements

```
registry.register(User)
registry.register(Article)
```

while executing the runserver command, I get the following error

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f3a680547d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapp
er
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
 line 102, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in 
validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34
, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get
_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _pop
ulate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load
_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import
_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 127, in
 get_user_model
    user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 271, in get
_model
    self._populate()
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _pop
ulate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load
_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import
_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/xxxx/maldio/maldio_project/links/models.py", line 115, in <module>
    registry.register(User)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/actstream/registry.py", line 85, in register
    self[model_class] = setup_generic_relations(model_class)
  File "/home/xxxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/actstream/registry.py", line 39, in setup_gene
ric_relations
    setattr(Action, attr_value, None)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actions_with_auth_user_as_actor'
```

Is there something that I missed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: While running *what* code?

Comment: updated the question more with detailed error and execution of runserver command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with version 0.5.1 of django-activity-stream. You can fix this error by removing 0.5.1 and installing 0.5 version.

You can track this bug here:

https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/issues/208

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're "User" variable has a null object in it, rather than a valid User object.

What is the code you are using to create the "User" and "Article" objects that you are passing in the functions that you show?

Comment: I am using the User model from django-contrib-auth, for which I do have some entries. Correct me if I am wrong if that is not what you meant by a null object.